# Vertical aligning border of inline-block divs

Tags: html, css, position

I have three `div`s aligned vertically using `display:inline-block`.

https://jsfiddle.net/46t1kqmk/

For the right border, styled the `:after` of the `div`. Now alignment of the border is not proper.

How can I align all the borders?

Is there a better way to add the border?

Comment: have you tried to search on SO before posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `top: 50%;` and `transform:translateY(-50%);`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46t1kqmk/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `:after`

You can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to apply left margins and then apply a right margin to `:last-child`. Much cleaner.

Code:

```css
p,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.col1 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col2,
.col3 {
  width: 20%;
}
.col1 ~ .col {
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}
.col:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <h5>Test title</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col col2">
    <h4>Test</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col col3">
    <h4>Test</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I have different content in the actual case. And need the border in same height. so border for the div not apt in my case.